# Code changes not displaying on frontend

Tags: magento-1.9

So I've pushed a load of changes live to my site, I flush the cache, I clear the browser cache, I've empty /var/cache and none of my changes display.

I've checked the whole site and it's not a case of me updating the wrong files to the wrong template.

Has anyone got anything else I've missed out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out is was an issue with APC, it wasn't being flushed on file changes

set apc.stat to 1 solved this issue

Comment: Please don't forget to accept your own answer after 48hours as accepted :) http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer